# How to remotely access application

Tags: remote-access, rdp, remoteapp

Is there an application which can be used to remotely access and start application on a server without using RDP.

The main reason for this is security are security issue when user has a full access to server with RDP. I know it is possible to set restriction on user roles, but I would like to know if there is an application that can actually complete this? Would that be some sort of cloud?

Thanks for helping and clearing this out for me

Comment: psexec will allow you to remotely start a service but if its not a client/server type app you won't be able see the console.

Comment: Psexex is not such a safe solution when connecting to a remote location over internet (not vpn).  It uses windows network capabilities,  so there has to be some sort of port mapping on remote machine.

Comment: Hmm didn't see anything about vpn being used "remote access" does not neccessarily imply this. Either way ports will be open thus exposing you to security issues.  This also doesn't necessarily have anything to do with a cloud solution.

Answer (score -2):

If it's just an executable, there's always the option of setting up a network share and running it from there.

If you're needing platform independence or if this method won't work, your best bet may be to created a very restricted account on the RDP host and go that route.

What type of network is it, and what's the application?